# How to upload a file to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am fairly new to SharePoint and I was not able upload a file to SharePoint successfully.

Currently, I am only able to add javascript to the HTML Source section of SharePoint [SharePoint HTML Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrZeh.png), but not able to call the file or upload the file to SharePoint.

How can I achieve this. Any assistance would be apperciated.

Also, I would like reference to SharePoint 2010 Documentation. I would like to be able to make mods on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this demo:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/Style%20Library/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script><script src="/Style%20Library/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function uploadFile() {

    var filePath = "c:\\test.pdf";
    var url= "http://Site/Shared Documents/test.pdf";

    var soapEnv =
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soap:Body>\
            <CopyIntoItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>\
                <SourceUrl>" + filePath + "</SourceUrl>\
                    <DestinationUrls>\
                        <string> "+ url + "</string>\
                    </DestinationUrls>\
                    <Fields>\
                        <FieldInformation Type='Text' DisplayName='Title' InternalName='Title' Value='Test' />\
                    </Fields>\
                <Stream>base64Binary</Stream>\
            </CopyIntoItems>\
        </soap:Body>\
    </soap:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://site/_vti_bin/copy.asmx",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems"); },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
    alert(soapEnv);
}


function processResult(xData, status) {
    alert("Uploaded SuccessFully");
}
 </script>
<input name="Upload" onclick="uploadFile()" type="button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// First locate your sharepoint site and hit service in browser.
// It is like "http://fullsitename/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
// If you do not get 404 then it accessible and seems working for current user.
// Add its reference to project.

// SharePoint 2010 provides web service list.asmx which can be used. 
// It can be used with Jquery Ajax calls as well.
// In below example i updated listitem by attaching attachment to it.
// Care fully add web reference in project or you will not get ServiceWebReference.Lists class.
// ServiceWebReference can have different name, as you prefer.
// This is working POC...... Hope this help :)

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string srcUrl = @"C:\Users\prasads\Downloads\birthdaypic.gif";

if (!File.Exists(srcUrl))
{
throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} does not exist",
srcUrl), "srcUrl");
}

FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(srcUrl);
string fileName = fStream.Name.Substring(3);
byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
fStream.Close();

ServiceWebReference.Lists listService = new ServiceWebReference.Lists();
listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

try
{
string addAttach = listService.AddAttachment("mylistname", "1", fileName, contents);

}

catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
{
// catch error
}
}
```